# What kind of markup is this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf-generation

I am trying to generate some PDFs from an MVC view and it's been quite a ride. I eventually came across [this](http://nyveldt.com/blog/post/Introducing-RazorPDF) and am trying to use it but it has this strange markup as shown below (it's based on ITextSharp):

```
<row>
    <cell borderwidth="0.5" left="false" right="false" top="false" bottom="true">User Name</cell>
    <cell borderwidth="0.5" left="false" right="false" top="false" bottom="true">Description</cell>
    <cell borderwidth="0.5" left="false" right="false" top="false" bottom="true" horizontalalign="right">Lucky Number</cell>
    <cell borderwidth="0.5" left="false" right="false" top="false" bottom="true" horizontalalign="right">Doubled</cell>
</row>
```

[Source](https://github.com/RazorAnt/RazorPDFSample/blob/master/RazorPDFSample/Views/Home/ReportSample.cshtml)

All I am really trying to do at this point is set the width of the column (cell, as it's called here) but `cell` isn't accepting my `style: width` or `width` or anything.

How can I use this thing? Are there any better ways to render PDF from MVC view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have said this is iTextSharp xml.  Here is a post that posts list the valid XML elements.  [How to create tables in a PDF document using XML and iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807330/how-to-create-tables-in-a-pdf-document-using-xml-and-itextsharp)

It looks like you could potentially use CDATA tags to set the width.

Comment: That seems so annoying...  I feel like setting width of an element is like the simplest thing; it shouldn't be so difficult.

Comment: iTextSharp is, IMO, very difficult to work with.  It is not that straightforward if you did it in C# either.

Comment: Is there something you recommend?  I am trying to use wkhtmltopdf, now, but I am having trouble with the .EXE and am hoping I can use a .DLL, instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285363/running-exe-from-mvc

Comment: wkhtmltopdf would be the option I would recommend.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do would be to create your view in html and convert it to a pdf then send that as your action result.

Simple way to get the html of a razor template
http://razorengine.codeplex.com/

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

Pdf conversion
http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/EOPdf/Default.aspx

Comment: That costs like $600...  Probably why I've never heard of it until now.  Got anything cheaper?

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/a/2129296/324497 you could try <a href="http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/">wkhtmltopdf</a>. There are also other solutions offered in for that question.

Comment: Look like it's XML using the iText convention.  http://stderr.org/doc/libitext-java-doc/www/tutorial/ch07.html

Unless you have a reason for doing it with XML I'd avoid the extra complexity and go with html to pdf conversion.